# Is $(x^2+y^2)^a$ Lebesgue-integrable in $\mathbb R^2\setminus E$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have to dermine for which $a\in \mathbb R$, the function $f_a(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^a\in\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R^2\setminus E)$, where $E$ is defined as
$$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 1,y\le \sqrt{|x|} \}.$$
The first thing I noticed is  that $f_a(-x,y)=f_a(x,y)\implies \iint_{\mathbb R^2\setminus E}f_a=2\iint_{(\mathbb R^2\setminus E)\cap\{x\ge 0\}}f_a.$
I decomposed the set of integration as $E_1\cup E_2$, where $E_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x\ge 0,x^2+y^2>1\}$ and $E_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x\ge 0,\sqrt x \le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\}.$
$f_a$ is continuous in $\mathbb R^2\setminus E$ and positive so it is a measurable and positive function. Furthermore, since $E\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is closed, $\mathbb R^2\setminus E$ is open hence $\mu_2$-measurable.
Then for Tonelli's theorem we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2\setminus E}f_a=2\int_{\xi}^{\pi/2}\int_{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}}^1r^{2a+1}drd\theta+2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_1^{+\infty}r^{2a+1}drd\theta, \text{ with }\xi\in(0,\pi/2).$$
I think that, in order to be convergent, since $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\to 0$ for $\theta\to \pi/2$, the integrand of the integral in $E_2$ has to respect the condition $-2a-1<1\iff a>-1$ but this condition gives me a contradiction with the convergence for the second integral. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can someone help me with this problem pls?

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed missing something. Note that the first integral is
$$
\int_\xi^{\pi/2}\int_{\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}}^1r^{2a+1}drd\theta = \int_\xi^{\pi/2}\left[1 - \frac{1}{2a+2}\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\right)^{2a+2}\right]d\theta.
$$
So it's $\cos^{2a+2}\theta$ that's determining convergence near $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Ok but before integrating I have to impose $2a+1>-1$ correct?

Comment: @Vajra no, because the lower limit of integration is never 0 on $(\xi, \pi/2)$, so the integral is always finite on the interior of the region of integration.

Comment: if $\theta\to \pi/2$ then $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\to 0$ no?